# TypeScript definitions for Server-Sent Events

Tags: beginner, typescript

I could not find any definitions of the EventSource object that belongs to [Server-Sent Events](http://dev.w3.org/html5/eventsource/), so I create the definitions. That's how they look like:

```
declare var EventSource : sse.IEventSourceStatic;

declare module sse {

    enum ReadyState {CONNECTING = 0, OPEN = 1, CLOSED = 2}

    interface IEventSourceStatic extends EventTarget {
        new (url: string, eventSourceInitDict?: IEventSourceInit);
        url: string;
        withCredentials: boolean;
        CONNECTING: ReadyState; // constant, always 0
        OPEN: ReadyState; // constant, always 1
        CLOSED: ReadyState; // constant, always 2
        readyState: ReadyState;
        onopen: Function;
        onmessage: (event: IOnMessageEvent) => void;
        onerror: Function;
        close: () => void;
    }

    interface IEventSourceInit {
        withCredentials?: boolean;
    }

    interface IOnMessageEvent {
        data: string;
    }
}
```

Also [available on GitHub](https://github.com/yankee42/typescript-server-sent-events/blob/master/sse.d.ts).

I am new to TypeScript so I wonder if this definition is OK with common best practices and whether it could be improved.

Comment: Does this definition mean that you're attaching to the events like
`eventSource.on('onmessage', ...)` ? (note: I'm also a beginner in TS)

Comment: Just want to say I'm using your definition in a project and it's working fine and helping my concentrate on more productive things. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

According to your definition file, I'm assuming there's a global class called `EventSource`

If that's the case, I have the following improvements:

- Avoid `Function` (or `Object` or `Array`), describe the signature accurately (like you did with `onmessage`). If you don't know the return type or the argument, apply `any` liberally. At least you're explicit about not knowing.
- TypeScript has literal string, number and enum types, so you could do something like `CONNECTING: ReadyState.CONNECTING`

All in all, it's a fine definition file.